# Track email user is not working with Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-tag-manager

I'm trying to have the information about the user email each time somebody access to a website. This information is stored in the PHP session variable. So I define the dataLayer with the email data and also attach the event gtm.load as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.js"></script>
    <?php
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['email'] = 'mimail@gmail.com';
        echo 'test ' . $_SESSION['email'];
    ?>
    <script>
      var dataLayer = [
          {'email':'<?php echo $_SESSION["email"]; ?>',
           'event':"gtm.load"}
      ];
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="mailto:joseantonio.cuenca@perseivivarium.com">Track</a>

    <!-- Google Tag Manager -->
    <noscript><iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-PFG3F5"
    ...
    })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXXXX');</script>
    <!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
    </body>
</html>
```

But accessing to Google Tag Manager I can't track the data in events as it is supposed to be. dataLayer is loaded fine because if I console.log this I have:

```
Object {email: "mimail@gmail.com", event: "gtm.load"}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to supply your own "gtm.load" event, and in fact GTM will just another gtm.load when the code is loaded further down the page (gtm.load is the event that is set automatically when the page is completely loaded).

If you set a dataLayer before the GTM tag you do not need to define a custom event at all, you can simply access the datalayer at the default events (gtm.js when the code is first loaded, gtm.dom when the DOM is ready and gtm.load when the page and all assets have loaded). So drop the event and try to access the variable at the pageview (trigger type also set to pageview).